# classes having destructor and new operator.‏

Tags: c++, overloading, destructor, operator-keyword

I overloaded the new operator with the following code fr it.

```
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout<<"size=>"<<size<<endl;
    return malloc(size);
}
```

Now, I tried to allocate memory for a class object using this overloaded `new`.
Say the class body is defined as:

```
class c
{
     char ch;
};
```

I wrote the following statements

```
c * p=new c; // gives me the output size=>1 OK Fine..
c *p=new c[100]; // gives me the output size => 100 OK fine.
```

but now I add a destructor to the class.
So the new body becomes:

```
class c
{
     char ch;
     public:
                  ~c(){}
};
```

Now I again wrote the same statements

```
c *p= new c;// gives me the output size=>1 OK Fine..
c *p=new c[100]; // gives me the output size => 108.
```

Where does this extra 8 come from?

I tried to allocate array again using the same statement and again I got size as 108. (I have a 64 bit OS, so I guess a extra pointer is being allocated each time).

Why is my compiler allocating this extra pointer or if its some else) when we have a destructor in the class?

Comment: Also note, that you overloaded `operator new` incorrectly. It should throw `std::bad_alloc` in case of allocation error and not return 0. And it should be `operator new[]` for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not worry about this behavior, as it is implementation defined.

In your particular case, compiler stores the information about the size of array, so it could know, how many elements is stored, when calling destructors.

In case of POD structure, that has no any nontrivial destructor, compiler does not invoke it and so it does not need an information about array size. 8 is probably `sizeof(size_t)`, as you can store `size_t` elements in an array.

Again, all it is implementation defined and just speculation.